# flutter showing Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Filter error, bad data error

Tags: flutter, http, flutter-http

when I am trying to make an HTTP request in flutter I am receiving these errors on a particular API and I am unable to figure out what it means and how to resolve this error is it API is working  properly in postman and browser

```
> E/flutter (15337): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Filter error, bad data
E/flutter (15337): #0      _FilterImpl.processed (dart:io-patch/filter_patch.dart:11:32)
E/flutter (15337): #1      _FilterSink.addSlice (dart:io/data_transformer.dart:537:29)
E/flutter (15337): #2      _FilterSink.add (dart:io/data_transformer.dart:521:5)
E/flutter (15337): #3      _ConverterStreamEventSink.add (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:72:18)
E/flutter (15337): #4      _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:111:24)
E/flutter (15337): #5      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
E/flutter (15337): #6      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter (15337): #7      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)
E/flutter (15337): #8      CastStreamSubscription._onData (dart:_internal/async_cast.dart:85:11)
E/flutter (15337): #9      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
E/flutter (15337): #10     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter (15337): #11     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)
E/flutter (15337): #12     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
E/flutter (15337): #13     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
E/flutter (15337): #14     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)
E/flutter (15337): #15     _HandleErrorStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:256:10)
E/flutter (15337): #16     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
E/flutter (15337): #17     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
E/flutter (15337): #18     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter (15337): #19     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)
E/flutter (15337): #20     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
E/flutter (15337): #21     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:14)
E/flutter (15337): #22     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:706:11)
E/flutter (15337): #23     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:663:7)
E/flutter (15337): #24     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1346:47)
E/flutter (15337): #25     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
E/flutter (15337): #26     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1162:7)
E/flutter (15337): #27     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1202:23)
E/flutter (15337): #28     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1354:13)
E/flutter (15337): #29     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
E/flutter (15337): #30     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1162:7)
E/flutter (15337): #31     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1202:23)
E/flutter (15337): #32     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter (15337): #33     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
E/flutter (15337):
```

I have tried adding other API which is am using in my application and code is working properly but for it is giving above exception and stops after HTTP call.

```
 Future<Null> getNewHomeData() async {
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });


   
     final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(Uri.encodeFull(APIs.url_HomePage)));
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
    try {

      print(response.body);
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        final home = homeNewFromJson(response.body);

        homeBanner = home.advImg;
        homeContent = home.infoText;
        shopCat = home.shopCat;
        storeImg = home.storeImg;
        topSellings = home.topSellings;
        modularFurniture = home.modularFurniture;
        decorFurniture = home.decorFurniture;
        banner1 = home.banner1;
        banner2 = home.banner2;
        banner3 = home.banner3;
        banner4 = home.banner4;
        banner5 = home.banner5;
      }
    } on Exception catch (e) {
     print(e);
    }
```

Comment: please paste your API code.

Comment: Can you paste the response data in postman?